# Sync Rally with another bug tracking solution

Tags: .net, rally, agile-project-management

I'm looking for a solution to sync (in both directions) between our Rally subscription and another bug tracking system (FIT http://www.fittrackingsolutions.com/ in particularly)

At first, I thought that I have to get Rally data via REST APIs and update FIT data via it's SOAP API, and vice versa

Then I see this: http://www.rallydev.com/help/rally-integrations-faq-and-best-practices

Seems that Rally itself has a kindof service connector that helps sync itself with other systems. However, I don't know what is Rally's Enterprise Integration Framework (EIF), also where is the rally2_*_connector.exe and config.xml files mentioned in the link ...

Anyone has an idea on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Rally Enterprise Integration Framework (EIF) is the core codebase shared by Rally-built and supported connectors (Quality Center, Bugzilla, etc.) Currently, this codebase isn't something that Rally customers can leverage directly in their own code.

You're on the right track in terms of toolkits available for building your sync connector to FIT: we'd recommend Rally's REST API. There are a couple of supported REST toolkits that Rally provides for programmers:

http://developer.rallydev.com/help/rest-apis

There are newer REST tools in Java and Python too but these are alpha-level toolkits:

http://developer.rallydev.com/help/labs

Hope this helps - good luck with your sync connector!

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for the reply. I just realize that EIF does not support FIT, period. So the only solution for me is to build a sync connector myself. Before I accept your answer, could you let me know how do I build a connector so that it can automatically spot changes in Rally data. Based on REST documents, I do'nt see how I can do that. Cheers

Comment: Hi HuyNa - at the moment - our integrations poll Rally on a recurring basis (say every 5-10 minutes) querying for artifacts where the LastUpdateDate is inside that window.  This should be a pretty small list which can then be processed for changes that need to go out to another system.  Hope that high level info helps